# Android: How to automatically sign in to twitter with a bot account?

Tags: android, twitter, bots

I'm trying to create a crowd sourcing application that will send out information through Twitter. Hopefully, the user will turn on my application, which will periodically do some processing of information and send out a tweet with that information.

I would like to create a bot account that the application will sign in with, so the users don't have to sign in with their own, or make one if they don't have one.

Currently I have an application that will direct the user to a website to sign in with their own account information with Twitter (using signpost and jtwitter), but this is far from what I want.

I have gone through oAuth, Signpost, J4twitter and Twitter API ME, and I can't find anything in those that suggest this being possible or not (though I might have missed it).

Any help or pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you got your  J4TWITTER working with oAuth?

Comment: Look here for auto tweet options http://www.bitrebels.com/social/7-ways-to-set-up-your-auto-tweets/       I understand that it may not be the answer to your question but may be you can derive something from here